# actual time webpage has been used with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help me, i have to calculate the actual time user spent on webpage i.e the time he does activities on webpage like mouse moves, key press etc.
I have script to calculate total time he spent on webpage.

```js
var start;
var end;
$(document).ready(function() {
  start = new Date().getTime();
  $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    end = new Date().getTime();  
    console.log("Time Difference : ");
    console.log(end - start);
  });     
});
```

I need the actual time he used that time, not the total time he has opened the page.
Please help. Any help will be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: good browsers have `window.performance` - use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timer to start and stop depending on what events you want to track.

If you want to track while the user has the window focused you can do something like:

```
var start,
    end,
    total = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  start = performance.now();

  $(window).on('blur', function() {
    end = performance.now();
    total += end - start
  })

  $(window).on('focus', function() {
    start = performance.now();
  })

  $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    end = performance.now(); 
    total += end - start 
    console.log("Time Difference : ");
    console.log(total);
  });             
});
```

If you want to track other events instead or as well, then you can have them trigger the start and end. e.g. `$(window).on('keydown mousemove', ...`

Comment: can you help me how can we calculate the time activity i.e mouse / cursor has moved on a webpage ? Please help..

Comment: @SachinGupta, if you want to track how long the mouse is moving you can start it with 'mousemove' but to stop you would need to either write a timeout or use a plugin like [jquery .mousestop](https://websanova.com/blog/jquery/jquery-mouse-stop-event-plugin)